# Is there an equivalent to doOnNext but ignoring any reactive results (except errors)?

Tags: java, project-reactor

Presently I am doing this

```
final ReactiveHashOperations<String, String, String> ops = redisTemplate.opsForHash();

var theMonoIWant =
  Mono.fromCallable(this::generateSomeComplexDataThatProducesTheValueIWant)
    .flatMap(
      theValueIWant -> {
        ... there is something here ...
        return ops.putAll(somewhere, something)
          .filter(success -> success)
          .switchIfEmpty(
             Mono.error(IllegalStateException::new)
          )
          .thenReturn(theValueIWant);
      }
    );
```

I also tried this and it worked, but I am thinking it may be a fluke it did, because I don't know how long it will actually take to complete the subscription and there may be a race condition for it.

```
final ReactiveHashOperations<String, String, String> ops = redisTemplate.opsForHash();

var theMonoIWant =
  Mono.fromCallable(this::generateSomeComplexDataThatProducesTheValueIWant)
    .doOnNext(
      theValueIWant -> {
        ops.putAll(somewhere, something)
          .filter(success -> success)
          .switchIfEmpty(
             Mono.error(IllegalStateException::new)
          )
          .subscribe();
       }
    );
```

But what I am looking for is something like

```
var theMonoIWant =
  Mono.fromCallable(this::generateSomeComplexDataThatProducesTheValueIWant)
    .doSubscriptionOnNextButIgnoreTheReturnValueUnlessItsAnError(
      theValueIWant -> 
        ops.putAll(somewhere, something)
          .filter(success -> success)
          .switchIfEmpty(
             Mono.error(IllegalStateException::new)
          );
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the first solution is the idiomatic one.

"doSubscriptionOnNext" is quite literally `flatMap`.

Ignoring the value(s) from said inner subscription is something better described in the inner publisher via composition rather than trying to predict all possible patterns as top-level flatMap variants.

`ignoreElements()` or in your case `thenReturn` are good ways of achieving that in the flatmapping function.